# Two inline table cell DIVs are causing vertical shift in one of them

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I searched for this but I can't seem to find a similar case that had an answer to it. Sorry if it has been addressed previously.

I have a section of a html page that looks, on a basic level, like this:

```
<div id=wrap>
    <div id=lb>
         Content
    </div>
    <div id=rb>
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

These basically break up my body into a left section (LB) and a right section (RB).
With corresponding CSS (Not showing a CSS Reset, but a generic one is in use as well; ... indicate other code is present but N/A):

```
#bwrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 display:inline-table;
 ...
}
#lb {
 width: 71.5%;
 display: table-cell;
 ...
}
#rb {
  width: 28.5%;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 30px 6px 7px 6px;
  border-left: 1px #6A6A6A solid;
  border-right: 1px #6A6A6A solid;
 }
```

I started right to left and filled in content in #RB; everything was perfect. However as soon as I started working in #LB I noticed that all my content within #RB shifted down to line up with the bottom of #LB's content. Even though the content nor the DIV overlaps. 
The specific content that did this was a google calendar  embed into #LB.
Everything looks completely normal except the shift down in #RB.

Anyone know where I went wrong? I tried to mess with floats and absolute positioning but none of it had any effect, most of it actually made the situation worse.

Comment: Thank you all! I used some of what you all suggested and it is perfect now!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Don't use display: table-cell, it's ugly and doesn't work consistently on all browsers, You should be able to do fine with floats and widths.

Also using padding or margins on the same element as an element that has a width defined is not a good idea, again browser incompatibilities make it a nightmare to work with.

I suggest you do something like:

```
<div id="wrap">
   <div id="lb">
       content
   </div>
   <div id="rb">
      <div id="rp">
           more content
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

with css:

```
#wrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 display: block;
 ...
}
#lb {
 width: 71.5%;
 display: inline; //not actually necessary
 float: left;
 ...
}
#rb {
  width: 28.5%;
  display: inline; //again not necessary
  float: right;
 }
 #rp{
  border-left: 1px #6A6A6A solid;
  border-right: 1px #6A6A6A solid;
  padding: 30px 6px 7px 6px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Live example http://jsfiddle.net/wfyVy/

Answer (score 0):

It's jumping down because the extra padding and border you have defined to rb is adding to the overall width of the container, making it no longer 28.5%. Try this:

```
#lb {
 width: 70%;
 display: table-cell;
 ...
}
#rb {
  width: 20%;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 30px 6px 7px 6px;
  border-left: 1px #6A6A6A solid;
  border-right: 1px #6A6A6A solid;
  oveflow:hidden;
 }
```

Update: if changing it to the css above is not enough, try adding a float: left to both ids above.

Answer (score 0):

When you use paddings in elements with width % values, the paddings adds to the width value. Try reducing a little  bit the width to get a correct proportion.